# SQL Server 1B+ records table - best way to handle upserts?

Tags: sql-server

The company I work for is building a data mart that wants 7 years of data maintained within it. Unfortunately, one table is well over 1 billion records.

**My question** is this: what would be the best way to keep this table current? (Daily update or quicker)

I know the `MERGE` statement is quite beneficial for this but I'm hoping to not have to parse through 1 billion records for each `MERGE`. Table partitioning is out as we do not have the Enterprise edition of SQL Server.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: [Table partition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/create-partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2017). Partition the table based on age of the data. You can even store each partition on its own storage volume

Comment: Table Partitioning, Compression, and Columnstore indexes are available in all editions of SQL Server 2016 SP1 and later.

Answer (score 0):

there are several options here; two are explained above on the comment.
The answer depends on which operation you want to do on the records.
If you just want to modify your recent records, the best way is to keep those records on an active table and move other records to an archive table as an archive. this way you need a scheduled job to move unnecessary records to the archive table.
 
 
If you want also to have a reporting module, you may need to provide an additional table which holds some abstracts of data in such a way that you can extract the reports you want.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to seriously consider splitting the table. For example, see the [operational versus archive](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/276395/two-database-architecture-operational-and-historical) paradigm.

The first step of splitting the data up from such a massive table is to identify the [clustering index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251636) (*if* it has one) and all the other indexes as well, because you will want to avoid operations that cause big rebuilds and data shifting.

Otherwise, if you *need* to keep the status quo, with good indexes (you should bite the bullet and define one <sub>if they have somehow survived this long without one</sub>), you can rely on the query optimizer to do a quick [index seek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764) (much better than a scan, especially a **table scan**, which is the concern you seem to have). So just write your `MERGE` statement and make sure to use indexes in the `ON` clause (and avoid [using functions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3204/avoid-using-functions-in-where-clause/) on indexed columns at all costs!).